# Sql Server match whole word

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a SQL table, I need to find occurrence of a word (from list in another table). I created a function to find the matching values. Function works for finding substring but I need to do full word match with a caveat to accept allowed delimiters from another table.

Example -

```
"Ben" should match  
"Ben's" should not match  
"Ben, John" should match
"Ben,John" should not match
```

Table KeywordsList -

```
| Id  |  Keyword |
------------------
| 1   | Cov      |
| 2   | Cover    |
| 3   | Ben      |
```

Table DelimitersList -

```
| Id  |  Delimiters |
---------------------
| 1   |             | (single space)
| 2   | ,           |
```

Function definition -

```
Create function dbo.searchString(@inputString NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(1000)
BEGIN
        
DECLARE @strKeywords nvarchar(1000)
select @strKeywords = COALESCE(@strKeywords + ',','') + Keyword FROM (
   select charindex(keyword, @inputString) as indexVal, keyword
   from KeywordList
) keywords WHERE keywords.indexVal > 0

Return @strKeywords 
END
```

Note that I am using SQL Server 2012. And I need to apply this function on a column of another table so it has to be a function.

Comment: Have a look at Full Text Indexes.

Comment: I cannot make change in schema

Comment: Then, you're likely in for a world of "hurt". As this is far from simple.

Comment: I know :). And bigger challenge is using old version of SQL Server

Comment: SQL Server 2012 is, at least, still in extended support and support Full-text indexing; which is still what you really need here.

Comment: As I mentioned, schema changes is not an option

Comment: That, however, doesn't change what the solution is. If you can't, then speak to whomever can.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Using PATINDEX I can do regex search within text. Replacing CHARINDEX with PATINDEX works as desired. Below is the function

```
Create function dbo.searchString(@inputString NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(1000)
BEGIN
        
DECLARE @strKeywords nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @delimiters nvarchar(100)
SET @delimiters = ' ,' -- This can be done by selecting the delimiters from table as well
select @strKeywords = COALESCE(@strKeywords + ',','') + Keyword FROM (
   select PATINDEX('%[' + @delimiters + ']' + keyword + '[' + @delimiters + ']%', @inputString) as indexVal, keyword
   from KeywordList
) keywords WHERE keywords.indexVal > 0

Return @strKeywords 
END
```